# Display issue with TimePicker: Only current time is selectable

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I want to display a `TimePicker` with all time slot is available to select. But for me only the time slots after the current time is available to select.

Please check my code.

```
        final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog();
        timePickerDialog.initialize(new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
                now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                String selectedDateString = simpleDateFormat.format(now.getTime());


                tvTimePicker.setText(selectedDateString);


            }
        }, now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), now.get(Calendar.SECOND), false);

        Calendar minNowCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        timePickerDialog.setMinTime(minNowCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), minNowCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), minNowCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));


        timePickerDialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"Key");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
timePickerDialog.setMinTime(minNowCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), minNowCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), minNowCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```